# Wrong OpenGL viewport of widget inside QDockWidget

Tags: python, c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I am drawing stuff on a widget which is inside a QDockWidget and has a 1:1 squared aspect ratio. However, the drawing surface is not properly resized.

How it should work:

[image]

How it works:

[image]

The code just draws 4 points at corners (coords) and anotherone in the middle

```cpp
const float vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

resizeEvent (this keeps a 1:1 aspect ratio):

```cpp
void Renderer::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
    if (this->width() > this->height()){
        this->resize(this->height(), this->height());
    } else {
        this->resize(this->width(), this->width());
    }
}
```

---

I made a python MRE which works fine:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import (glClear, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, glEnable, glClearColor, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, glBegin, glColor, glVertex, glEnd,
                       glPointSize, GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_POINTS)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget


class Renderer(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QOpenGLWidget.__init__(self)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(700, 700)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Keeps 1:1 aspect ratio
        if self.width() > self.height():
            self.resize(self.height(), self.height())
        elif self.height() > self.width():
            self.resize(self.width(), self.width())
        QOpenGLWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glPointSize(100)
        glColor(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)
        glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH)
        glBegin(GL_POINTS)
        points = [[0, 0, 0],
                  [-1, 1, 0],
                  [-1, -1, 0],
                  [1, -1, 0],
                  [1, 1, 0]]
        for point in points:
            glVertex(point[0], point[1], point[2])
        glEnd()
        self.update()
```

However, the C++ version does not work like this. MRE of C++ version:

```cpp
#include "headers/renderer.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <iostream>

Renderer::Renderer(MainWindow *parent)
{
    this->parent = parent;
}

QSize Renderer::sizeHint() const {
    return QSize(700, 700);
}

void Renderer::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
    QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    if (width() > height()){
        resize(height(), height());
    } else {
        resize(width(), width());
    } 
}

void Renderer::initializeGL(){
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
}

void Renderer::paintGL(){
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(100);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.2);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3i(-1, 1, 0);
    glVertex3i(-1, -1, 0);
    glVertex3i(1, -1, 0);
    glVertex3i(1, 1, 0);
    glEnd();
    update();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to call `glViewport` every time the window is resized.

Comment: @Ripi2 I tried it, even in the resizeGL method but didnt worked. I found the error, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put a QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent(event); in the resizeEvent. Full code is in the answer.